# Enumerate returning multiple indexes as integer from list

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I am trying to get indexes for `adams` and `lewis` from a list.

```
Presidents = ['washington','adams','jeff','lewis']

def index():
    for index,name in enumerate(Presidents):
        if name == 'adams':
            return index

print(index())
```

How can I modify this function? So that when the function `index()` is called, it should return the index of `adams` and `lewis` as integers.

Comment: You can do `Presidents.index('adams')`, `Presidents.index('lewis')`. If you like'd to get indices as a list, you can use `[Presidents.index(name) for name in ['adams', 'lewis']]`

Comment: the index are 1 and 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Answer (score -1):

You can just reuse the index method.

> The method returns the index of the element in the list.
>
> If not found, it raises a ValueError exception indicating the element
>   is not in the list.

```
def index(name):
  return Presidents.index(name)


print(index('adams'))
print(index('lewis'))
```